# can't navigate to /home/username/Downloads

Tags: 14.04, command-line, 16.04, gnome-terminal

```
~$ pwd
/home/username
~$ cd Downloads
bash: cd: Downloads: No such file or directory
```

I run above commands and I can't navigate to Downloads directory neither from terminal or graphical user

I can navigate other directories, the problem only is with Downloads directory

I am using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: include the output of ls -a when in /home/username.

Comment: I did it already before posting. I can't see Downloads. However I can see Downloads in the graphical user interface. From GUI I also can't go in to the folder

Comment: Look if you find the `Downloads`-folder in the directory `/home/username/Desktop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You, or somebody, has deleted the Downloads directory. What you see in the GUI is a shortcut. That the shortcut's target is no longer existing doesn't make the shortcut disappear.

All you need to do is create that directory again:

```
mkdir Downloads
```

Comment: Perhaps I unintentionally deleted it, I really don't know how it happened. Yeah I know make directory command. I just asked you guys to see whether there is a way to bring the old Downloads directory with its content. However I couldn't find. I used mkdir in the end. Thanks for answer

Comment: @SemirUmutKurt If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.